# iPhone sqlite desc vs asc?

Tags: iphone, sql, database, sqlite, sdk

How come in my code when i use @"select Score from tblMed order by Score desc limit 10" everything works fine, but when I change "desc" to "asc" the scores don't show up???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because:

```
ORDER BY score ASC
```

...means that the lowest values will be at the top of the list - adding `LIMIT 10` to the query will return the first 10 records with the lowest scores, so I imagine you have entries with score values of zero and/or null.

Comment: Yes, they are all zeros, how do i make them not zeros, or not null?

Comment: @Steve: What would you like the lowest scores to be displayed as?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `NULL` scores in your records?

If you change the ordering to asc, then it would start with NULLs before selecting records with an actual value.

Comment: Right now the whole table is filled with zeros because i haven't play the game yet.  How do i Make it so they aren't null?